# What does UTypeAnnotation in CoreAnnotations do?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I checked the documentation but nothing's mentioned in it.

links referred are 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreAnnotations.html

and

http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreAnnotations.UTypeAnnotation.html

The only thing I understood from the links that it returns the unicode type class. Doesn't mention what "class" means for this case and what is the basis for classification

Answer (score 1):

This is used by the Chinese segmenter. See, for example, `edu/stanford/nlp/wordseg/Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.java`. It is then used in the Chinese Segmenter feature factory (`edu/stanford/nlp/wordseg/Gale2007ChineseSegmenterFeatureFactory.java`).

Comment: I understand where it is used. I looking for little more details like what are the categories (or types) for a unicode  character.